# Making a private Git repository public automatically after a period of time

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

Does anyone know a way to automatically make a Github Repository Public after a certain number of days. I want to keep my Github repository private for a certain period of time post which it automatically becomes public. Is this even possible? Or should I have to manually make it public after that period of time?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide a way to automatically change the visibility of a repository, but you can use [an API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#update-a-repository) to change it automatically when you're ready.  Or, if you prefer, you can change it manually.